# SSIS Script component size

Tags: c#, ssis, sizing, script-component

I have a problem while using a C# script component in SSIS. The main "Script Transformation Editor" window is cropped at the "Edit Script..." level. I can't see the Ok and Cancel buttons, so I can't save this script.
Do you have a solution ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key provides navigation.

My tab order shows

1. Name
2. Edit Script...
3. OK
4. Cancel
5. Help

I would hit the Tab until I see Name/Edit Script lit up and then count tabs until I've landed on OK